# Force WebBrowser control to create isolated cookie for application

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, cookies, activex

I have gone through many SO questions related to this – but not exactly this.  I have a `WebBrowser` control in a `Windows Forms` project.  Multiple instances of the application will be run from same windows server machine – with different user credentials for the website.

As we know, the web browser uses IE engine and it has session merging.

What is the best way to force the web browser control to use individual cookie folders so that each instance of the application wouldn’t mind cookie of the other application?

Note: IE8 is the browser installed on the server

**REFERENCE**

1. [InternetSetCookie function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385107(VS.85).aspx)
2. [WebBrowser Control Mishandling Cookies when Internet Explorer is Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700981/webbrowser-control-mishandling-cookies-when-internet-explorer-is-open)
3. [How to Clear WebBrowser Control Cookie in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71a5b2bb-f254-45b3-94a0-d194e335211c/how-to-clear-webbrowser-control-cookie-in-c?forum=winforms)
4. [Multiple WebBrower sessions / processes in one window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051365/multiple-webbrower-sessions-processes-in-one-window)
5. [c# WebRequest using WebBrowser cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650536/c-sharp-webrequest-using-webbrowser-cookie)
6. [How to delete Cookies from windows.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/c-webbrowser-control-how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form?rq=1)

> InternetSetCookie function: Cookies created by InternetSetCookie without an expiration date are stored in memory and are available only in the same process that created them. Cookies that include an expiration date are stored in the windows\cookies directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .NET WebBrowser not to share cookies with IE or other Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195844/make-net-webbrowser-not-to-share-cookies-with-ie-or-other-instances)